# how data stored in b-tree for composite key in mysql? i want to know about tree representation of data

Tags: mysql, database-administration, b-tree

how b-tree looks like for below composite key?
primary key(imei_no,data_received_time)

both imei_no and data_received_time are bigInt.

plz give answer with example.

Comment: You want to know the binary representations of index files? The fact that they are composites is a mute point. See this manual page on [Physical Structure of an InnoDB Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-physical-structure.html)

Answer (score 0):

The data would be stored as a btree automatically, because with `imei_no` + `data_received_time` being the primary key, a b-tree index will be created by the system. So lookup is fast, which is what a b-tree is all about. The table itself, however, is just a common table of course.

If you want to *show* the table data as a b-tree, then have your GUI layer apply a b-tree algorithm on the data and show it accordingly.

If you want to *store the table data* as a b-tree, then add an ID and a parent ID and link the records thus. This makes your data hierarchical, however, and you need recursion in SQL to retrieve it properly. This can be quite hard - with MySQL especially, lacking recursive WITH clauses. (Or you just retrieve the data raw and again have your GUI layer apply the ordering and presentation. But if it's your GUI layer doing all this work, why store the data hierarchical in the first place?) There are certainly better ways than a database table to store b-trees. So *if* you want to do this, ask yourself first, *why* you want to do it.

Comment: thanks for reply.i have table of rows(greater than 1 billions) and when i execute query it takes time to execute it.i want to minimize the time query takes.so i try to understand real mechanism of index and how b-tree structured by system for composite key.if u have any idea of how  to improve performance of mysql then please reply.

Comment: I don't think you need to know much about how indexes work internally. Simply create the indexes needed to quickly find your data. By defining primary and foreign keys properly, you have the most important indexes there automatically. Then add further indexes as needed. With large tables, you may also want to consider partitioning, if your Queries are still too slow. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: Maybe you'd like to show us a query that you consider too slow, so we'd have an example we can talk about?

Comment: select odom,latitude/10000000 as latitude,longitude/10000000 as longitude,imei_no,iovalue,data_received_time,continue_data_received_time,data_location 
 from gps_device_data_demo 
 where imei_no in (7781112889,70433357641,111111111211412) 
 and data_received_time >= 1441045800000 and data_received_time <=  1442921690850 
 Order by imei_no,data_received_time;       there are 1000 imei_no. .

Comment: we have done partition but query gets three times slower.

Comment: With 1000 different IMEI numbers, each IMEI still appears in an avarage of some million records. So an index on `imei_no` shouldn't be much help here. An index on `(imei_no, data_received_time )` on the other hand could help, provided that only a small percentage of the table would be in the results. Once you access too many records, a direct full table scan is usually faster.

Comment: As to partitioning: This is a difficult task. Deciding for the wrong criteria usually leads to a slow-down, as you'd suddenly read several table partitions instead of just one table.  I surmise that you mainly access current records, so an appropriate partition might be years for instance, where you usually access only the newest year / partition.

Comment: thanks for your reply .it will help me in future also.